# updating from mysql to mysqli newbie

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am converting my site from MySQL to MySQLi its not simple for me as I never coded anything in MySQLi, when each user sing-in he gets an unique access token and I need to convert this code to mysqli

```
<?php
    include('config.php'); 
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `points` int(20) NOT NULL,
        `refer` int(11) NOT NULL, 
        `user_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
        `access_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
    ");
    $row = null;
    $result = mysql_query("
        SELECT
        *
        FROM
        users
        WHERE
        user_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'
    ");

    if($result){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1){
            mysql_query("
                DELETE FROM
                users
                WHERE
                user_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "' AND
                id != '" . $row['id'] . "'
            ");
        }
    }

    if(!$row){
        $insertpoint=200;
        $refer=0;
        mysql_query(
            "INSERT INTO
            users
            SET
            `user_id` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "',
            `points` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($insertpoint) . "',
            `refer` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($refer) . "', 
            `access_token` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($token) . "'
        ");
    } else {
        mysql_query(
            "UPDATE
            users
            SET
            `access_token` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($token) . "'
            WHERE
            `id` = " . $row['id'] . "
        ");
    }
?>
```

So far I am at:

```
<?php
include('config.php'); 

$create_table =
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data
(
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`points` int(20) NOT NULL,
`refer` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`user_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`access_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)';
$create_tbl = $db->query($create_table);


$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `Data`
    WHERE user_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

?>
```

I know my code is bad but its working and I don't know how to convert further the `config.php` contains only info about database connect which is now I am getting in MySQLi

Comment: Your code's not *that* bad. `mysql` and `mysqli` are a little different, but are mostly the same. Just append `i` onto `mysql` functions and re-program your connection stuff, that's all you basically need to do here.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ and maybe binding parameters...

Comment: I would suggest you learn PHP PDO to execute prepared statements and avoiding very possible sql injections. PDO is not hard at all to learn and it makes you sleep easily at night knowing that you did your best.

Comment: Are you wanting to take the object oriented approach, or procedural? They are slightly different, but not a whole lot.

Comment: @Eduardo La Hoz Miranda  i know this is the best advice and this is what i am looking for but when i tried i could not get that much then i decided to convert it to mysqli atlest , if anyone can give me any help about PDO it will be more then welcome

Comment: @jh0 I found this guide helpful to learn pdo: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code that might help you. It demonstrates bind_param as well which you should use. You can use the same code for your UPDATES, INSERTS and DELETES (just don't call mysqli_stmt_fetch).

```
$query = "SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
$result = '';
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query))
{
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $userId);

    /* execute query */
    if (!(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)))
    {
        sprintf("Execute failed in %s: %s\n", __FUNCTION__, mysqli_error($conn);
        die();
    }

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name, $surname);

    /* fetch values */
    if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) $result = "$name $surname";

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
else
{
    sprintf("Prepare failed in %s: %s\n", __FUNCTION__, mysqli_error($conn));
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not put

```
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'
```

inside a

```
<<<SQL
```

As < < < SQL will continue until it hits SQL and NOT consider the function as a function, but a string, thus breaking your sql string!

I have a simple function I built that allows "$query=" on the first line and "$Results=GetDate($DBLink,$query);" on the second line. So all you have to remember from that moment is how to write the query and you'll get results, no more need for figuring out freakin mysqli stuff. LOL (Actually, there are two functions, one for GetData and one for UpdateData.) Been using it for a couple years, makes life much simpler. Usually put it in a "require_once()" file and forget about it from that moment, but use it constantly on every app. Ask and I'd be happy to post it.